# Dual booting Windows after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning

I have a laptop that had Windows 7 pro installed on partition `C:`.  I created a second partition of equal size and copied the c partition to what is e now. Then I upgraded the `C:` partition (Windows 7 Pro) to Windows 10.  What could I do now to create/edit the boot loader file so it gives me the option to boot into either `C:` or e partition at boot time?

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows 7 copy on drive E: is not bootable by default. It can be made bootable by editing Windows 7 registry on E: drive. (DosDrive mappings should be changed to reflect partition move)
2. Regarding licenses - if you have only a Windows 7 license you cannot use it for running Windows 7 and the upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10 using the same license (this is what Microsoft says).